# Firebase extension: Run Subscription Payments with Stripe doesn't return a sessionId

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

I have installed the "Run Subscription Payments with Stripe" extension in Firebase.

When I try the to subscribe a user to a plan I get an error saying "snap.data is not a function". I use the following code:

```
 db
      .collection('customers')
      .doc(cred.user.uid)
      .collection('checkout_sessions')
      .add({
        price: 'price_1GqIC8HYgolSBA35zoTTN2Zl',
        success_url: window.location.origin,
        cancel_url: window.location.origin,
      }).then(() => {
    // Wait for the CheckoutSession to get attached by the extension
      db
      .collection('customers')
      .doc(cred.user.uid)
      .collection('checkout_sessions').onSnapshot((snap) => {

          console.log(snap)

          const { sessionId } = snap.data();
          if ({sessionId}) {

            console.log(sessionId)
            // We have a session, let's redirect to Checkout
            // Init Stripe
            const stripe = Stripe('pk_test_ZEgiqIsOgob2wWIceTh0kCV4001CPznHi4');
            stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId });
          };
    });
  });
```

This is a .then variation on the code example provided by the Firebase team:

```
const docRef = await db
  .collection('customers')
  .doc(currentUser.uid)
  .collection('checkout_sessions')
  .add({
    price: 'price_1GqIC8HYgolSBA35zoTTN2Zl',
    success_url: window.location.origin,
    cancel_url: window.location.origin,
  });
// Wait for the CheckoutSession to get attached by the extension
docRef.onSnapshot((snap) => {
  const { sessionId } = snap.data();
  if (sessionId) {
    // We have a session, let's redirect to Checkout
    // Init Stripe
    const stripe = Stripe('pk_test_1234');
    stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId });
  }
});
```

I got an error with the await function, saying "Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function". So I refactered the code to a .then variant.

When I run this code from a button.addEventListener("click) I get an error saying snap.data is not a function.

I checked snap and it is populated

[image: snapshot of console.log()]

The customer gets created in Firestore and in Stripe dashboard, the customer session gets created.

What goes wrong here? There is a similair question on Stackoveflow ([Run Subscription Payments with Stripe Firebase Extension Webhook Not Firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63363098/run-subscription-payments-with-stripe-firebase-extension-webhook-not-firing#comment112043703_63363098)), but there is no answer, so I'm trying again.

Answer (score 2):

Your query:

```
  db
      .collection('customers')
      .doc(cred.user.uid)
      .collection('checkout_sessions')
```

can fetch possibly multiple documents at once.  The object it yields is a QuerySnapshot type object that can contain zero or more documents in the results et.  That's what your `snap` is here - a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot).  You'll notice that it doesn't have a `data()` method.  That's for DocumentSnapshot objects, where you know you either have a single document or not.

If you have a QuerySnapshot, you'll have to iterate it to get all possible document snapshots out of it, as illustrated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection).

But it seems that's not even what you want to do.  It looks like you want to access the document that was previously added using `add()`.  If that's what you want, you shouldn't be querying the entire collection as you are now.  Just locate the single document you want and [add a listener to it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-local-changes).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thought I didn't realy understand what the sessionId was, since I never query the way the code writen by the Firebase team is querying. If I query the database the way you describe there should be a "sessionsId" object in the "checkout_sessions collection"; but it isn't there.

Comment: I don't see a session ID anywhere in the code you've shown here, so I don't know where it's supposed to come from.  I just see a variable referencing a field of a document.  Not sure where you're expecting it to come from.

Comment: For what I can see the sessionID is extracted from the snap.data() and should be added in the firebase document via a webhook by Stripe. There is no sessionsID in the document to be found.;This is what the Firebase extensions documentation says: "To subscribe the user to a specific pricing plan, create a new doc in the checkout_sessions collection for the user. The extension will update the doc with a Stripe Checkout session ID which you then use to redirect the user to the checkout page."

Comment: I'm not sure I can really help you out any more using the information here.  It sounds like something is missing in your implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You need to listen to updates to the specific document that you juts added via the `.add()` function. This function returns a reference to that specific document: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/blob/next/firestore-stripe-subscriptions/POSTINSTALL.md#start-a-subscription-with-stripe-checkout

If you don't want to / can't use async/await syntax you will need to get that document reference from the `.then()` function: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web_6

```js
db.collection("customers")
  .doc(user)
  .collection("checkout_sessions")
  .add({
    price: "price_1I42zfKct2IqsPff6b6vFNKx",
    success_url: window.location.origin,
    cancel_url: window.location.origin,
  })
  .then((docRef) => {
    docRef.onSnapshot((snap) => {
      const { sessionId } = snap.data();
      if ({ sessionId }) {
        console.log(sessionId);
        // We have a session, let's redirect to Checkout
        // Init Stripe
        const stripe = Stripe("pk_test_ZEgiqIsOgob2wWIceTh0kCV4001CPznHi4");
        stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId });
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Oke, that makes sense. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this has been resolved. I had a similar issue and changed tsconfig.jason

```
 "compilerOptions": {
 ...
    "strict": false,
...
}
```

That did it for me.